# How to link a JMenuItem to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, exit, jmenuitem

Let's say I have a JMenuItem with a text inside "Exit", and a JButton with the text "Exit",
the command which JButton will use is System.exit(0), of course using Action Listener, Ok i Know, I can put the same codes when clicking on the JMenuItem, but isn't there a way, that when I click on the JMenuItem, the JButton is clicked so then the following commands are executed (JButton commands)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is create an `Action` object, and use that for both your `JButton` and your `JMenuItem`.

```
Action exit = new AbstractAction() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2581717261367873054L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };
exit.putValue(Action.NAME, "Exit");
exit.putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_X);

JButton exitButton = new JButton(exit);
JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem(exit);
```

Answer (score 4):

A good way to do this is to set the same `ActionListener` to both components. Like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton ("Exit");
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem ("Exit");

ActionListener exitaction = new ActionListener ()
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit (0);
    }
};

button.addActionListener (exitaction);
item.addActionListener (exitaction);
```

However, I would recommend against using `System.exit (0)`. The better way of closing the program (which I assume is basically a `JFrame`) is by setting

`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`

(where `frame` is the window of the program)

and calling `frame.dispose ()` in the `ActionListener`.

Comment: Actually, it is better to encapsulate this in an Action. That way, you can also use KeyBindings. As for the closing of the application, I find it a lot cleaner to rely on System.exit than praying for all my frames to be gone and that all my remaining Threads are daemon

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save the button as a class field

```
private JButton button;
```

and insert in the click event handler of the menu item the code

```
button.doClick();
```

but the solution of [SoboLAN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10739951/611595) is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I consider the best way to do this is to register the same ActionListener instance in the event listeners of both JMenuItem and JButton, it's like using the old Command design pattern.

I would not recommend trying to trick the events 'engine' like making the JMenuItem fire the event related to the pressing of the JButton, since that is not what's happening but what you seem to want is to reuse both actions to 2 distinct events.